# Mongo pull the data from array and change it to string using aggregation

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
_id:ObjectId("sdmiosdlgnjaksc") 

mixed: Array
 0:Array
    0:Array
       0:ObjectId("5dsoiucjnaov")
```

required output

```
_id:ObjectId("sdmiosdlgnjaksc") 

mixed: ObjectId("5dsoiucjnaov")
```

tried unwind , but it reduces only one layer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$unwind` twice:

```
 {$unwind:"$mixed"},
 {$unwind:"$mixed"}
```

Or, use 2x`$arrayElemAt` times or `$reduce` + `$arrayElemAt`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      mixed1: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$mixed",
              0
            ]
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      mixed2: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$mixed",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$$this",
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j5AnUmTrtri)